# How to use String.Replace method for html string

Tags: c#

I am having html code in string variable. In that I have  mutiple image tags and I want replace the src of image tag with new src.

I am using this code :

```
    foreach (MessagePart attchment in unseenMessage.FindAllAttachments())
    {
         attchments =  Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + attchment.FileName;
         string src="cid:"+ attchment.ContentId;
         string newsrc = "/Attachment/" + attchments;
         emailbody.Replace(src, newsrc);
         string filepath = "D:\\AceoCRM\\Aceo.Web\\Attachment\\" + attchments;
         using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.CreateNew))
         {

              fs.Write(attchment.Body, 0, attchment.Body.Length);
              fs.Close();
         }
         listOfAttachments.Add(attchments);
    }
```

Comment: and what the problem?

Comment: `Replace` doesn't change the string, it returns an updated string instead. So you need to assign it back to `emailbody`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse and replace tags inner html and images sources.

Edit:
Example: to replace src

```
var documnet = new HtmlDocument();
documnet.LoadHtml("HtmlString");
foreach (var href in documnet.DocumentNode.Descendants("img").Where(href => !href.OuterHtml.Trim().Contains("http")))
{
     try
     {
          //here image src URL being changed...
          href.Attributes["src"].Value = href.Attributes["src"].Value.Trim().StartsWith("//") ? String.Format("http:{0}", href.Attributes["src"].Value.Trim()) : String.Format("{0}/{1}", baseUrl, href.Attributes["src"].Value.TrimFromStart("//"));
          href.Attributes["srcset"].Value = href.Attributes["srcset"].Value.Trim().StartsWith("//") ? String.Format("http:{0}", href.Attributes["srcset"].Value.Trim()) : String.Format("{0}/{1}", baseUrl, href.Attributes["srcset"].Value.TrimFromStart("//"));
     }
     catch (NullReferenceException ex)
     {
         Log(ex);
     }
}
```

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack is nice, but I'd also recommend looking at [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery/)

Comment: Thanx for your answer .My code is also working .i was doing mistake, i was note updating variable thats why i was not abel to get updates